# Query to find out stored procedures using dynamic temp tables

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

Let's say I have 10,000 stored procedures in my database, each with a thousand LOC. A few of these stored procedures use dynamic temp tables. I want to find out all those stored procedures which use dynamic temp tables.

Can someone help me with the most optimized query for this task?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "dynamic temp tables"?

Comment: Dynamic temp table means when table is not created explicitly. Also, my DB is SQL Sever 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this:

```
SELECT s.name As schema_name, p.name as procedure_name
FROM sys.procedures p
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE object_definition(object_id) like '%create table #%'
```

Tough I'm nut sure what you mean by "dynamic temp tables" and I'm also not sure about performance, but this should give you a list of all stored procedures that contains the text `create table #` - that's the creation of a temporary table.

[See a live demo or rextester.](http://rextester.com/BOPVQ63806)

### Update (again)

Now that you have clarified what you mean by "dynamic temp tables", all you need to do is change the condition in the where clause:

```
SELECT s.name As schema_name, p.name as procedure_name
FROM sys.procedures p
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE object_definition(object_id) like '%[^insert] into #%'
```

Comment: This is not the way to create a dynamic temp tables. when we give table definition, we are creating tables explicitly.

Comment: select txtVersion,txtLevel,txtParameters,txtParameterType,txtParametersDesc,                        
 case when flgPricePerUnitApplicable = 1                            
  then '1'              
  else '0'                            
 end as 'flgPricePerUnitApplicable',txtLevelName into #temp                            
 from                            
  testowner.ProjectLTSMstPARAMETERS with (nolock)                            
 where                            
  flgLicenseParameter = 1        This is an exmaple of dynamic temp table creation where temp table schema is not defined.

Comment: Then change the condition to `%into #%`... see my edited answer.

Comment: But that will give me those SPs also where allkind of  insert operations are performed. Simple inserts also.

Comment: Only those that insert into a temporary table. I do have a way to narrow it down even further, will update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: I've updated my answer again, including the link to rextester.